# The app prints code on screen instead of view in rails 3.1.0

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In our app, a selection box is added dynamically to new rfq form. The problem is instead of the view, the code gets printed on the screen. The code is based on railscasts.com #197 with some modification.

Here is the code in rfqs/_form_new.html.erb:

```
  <div id="std">
  <%= render :partial => 'standards', :collection => @rfq.standards, :locals => { :f => f } %>
  </div>
  <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Std", f, :standards, @rfq %></p>
```

Here is the screen shot after clicking "Add Std":

[image: screen shot for "Add Std"]

Here is the link_to_add_fields:

```
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association, obj)
    if association == :standards
      new_object = obj.standards.build
    else
      new_object = obj.test_items.build
    end

    link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"escape_javascript(render :partial => association.to_s, :collection => new_object, :locals => { :f => f })\")")
  end
```

Here is the add_fields:

```
function add_fields(link, association, content) {
  var new_id = new Date().getTime();
  var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
  $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
}
```

The relationship between rfq and standard is HABTM. In railscasts.com example, the relationship is has_many and belongs_to.

Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are passing in a string with escape_javascript... in it to the link_to_function.

You probably want to render the partial immediately and put that in the link_to_function

```
link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", #{escape_javascript(render :partial => association.to_s, :collection => new_object, :locals => { :f => f })})")
```

Comment: Tried after removing the quotation mark. Nothing rendered. Without backward slash, the 3rd arg disappeared completely, and still nothing rendred.

Comment: Here is the html source for with \:  <a onclick="add_fields(this, &quot;standards&quot;, #{escape_javascript(render :partial =&gt; association.to_s, :collection =&gt; new_object, :locals =&gt; { :f =&gt; f })}); return false;" href="#">Add Std</a>